# webkit float issue

Tags: html, css, webkit, css-float

I have some problem where i set 2 floated div elements, one of div contain **select** element, when the page loaded the divs didn't have the problem, but as soon i click on of the element(s) on select box, the div that positioned in right shift to bottom?

Here some example code about what i'm talking:

```
#div1,#div2{float:left}
#div1{width:200px;margin-right:10px}
#div2{width:760px}
```

and the html

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="div1"><!--here the select goes--></div>
  <div id="div2"><!--here the table goes--></div>
</div>
```

And here the screenshot for what happening after and before:
[Screenshot](http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/6834/screenshot.jpg)

No javascript involved at all

I've tested with Opera (Presto), Firefox (Gecko), IE8 (Trident) and no problem, seem it only appears on Webkit based browser, since i've tested on Chrome 2, SR Iron & QTWeb

PS: try to ignore the ugly table header, soon i'll fix it (it's currently ok on Opera, Firefox, IE8 browser)

Comment: Could you supply some of the html as well? Are both of these divs nested inside another div? Is that all the CSS that's being applied to the divs?

Answer (score 1):

In the css try:

```
#div1{width:200px;margin-right:10px;float:left;}
#div2{width:760px;float:right;}
```

Hopefully that will fixed the selecting problem but because your using fixed sizes it will still break if the window size is to small.

Comment: and the better way to do that without affecting other browser was target for webkit only, but how?

Comment: Can you provided more of the code, I can't duplicate the problem with the snippets you gave. I am thinking it may have to do with the table or more of the styling.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing too.  Except, he'll probably need a margin-right on #div2 to space it some from that side.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target webkit browsers only using css:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
{    
    "element/class or id here"{
      whatever you need here, ie: padding-top: 24px;
    }    
}
```

Comment: As weird as it seems some older versions of Opera will pick it up.